# Excel DataValidation dropdown value coming back null

Tags: excel, spring-boot, java-8, apache-poi

I am trying to retrieve a Cell value from an file File.xlsm using Apache POI 4.0.1.

The cell has a data validation using a list for dropdown values Yes/No.

I pass in the Cell to a setter method where I call another method to retrieve value based upon cell type.

```
public void setSomething(Cell cell){
this.var=parseCellValue(cell);
}
```

And in parseCellValue I retrieve cell value based upon the type of cell

```
switch(cell.getCellType()){
case NUMERIC:.....
case STRING:......
case BLANK: return null;
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the dropdown value which is selected but it returns BLANK type cell even though value is selected.

Please advise on how to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not reproducible for me. This question shows why we always need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

So let's have a such:

`ExcelDataValidation.xlsx` looks like:

[image]

Column `D` has data validation set.

Then folowing code is able getting all cell values properly:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelParseCellValue {

 static void setSomething(Cell cell) {
  Object var = parseCellValue(cell);
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(var));
 }

 static Object parseCellValue(Cell cell) {
  Object var = null;
  switch (cell.getCellType()) {
   case NUMERIC:
    var = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    break;
   case STRING:
    var = cell.getStringCellValue();
    break;
   case BLANK:
    var = null;
    break;
   default:
    var = null;
  }
  return var;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelDataValidation.xlsx"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    setSomething(cell);
   }
  }  
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\java>c:\java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java -cp .;.\*;poi-4.1.1\*;poi-4.1.1\lib\*;poi-4.1.1\ooxml-lib\* ExcelParseCellValue
Text
Number
Amount
Validation
Text1
1.0
1234.56
Yes
Text2
2.0
789.12
No
Text3
3.0
34567.89
Yes
```